# SQL code conversion into a single Django ORM query?

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to convert the following SQL query in to a single Django query in order to minimize number of executed sql queries, however I'm not able to do that except using a for-loop.

I appreciate it if anyone could provide me the intended Django query

SQL Query:

```
select FUND_ID, REPORT_DATE, PURCHASE_NAV_PER_SHARE
FROM FUNDS_HISTORY
WHERE REPORT_DATE = (
   SELECT Max(REPORT_DATE)
   FROM FUNDS_HISTORY fund_history
   where fund_history.FUND_ID = FUNDS_HISTORY.FUND_ID
)
```

models:

```
class Fund(models.Model):
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)


class History(models.Model):
    fund = models.ForeignKey('funds.Fund', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    purchase_nav_per_share = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    report_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Please share the related models.

Comment: please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can annotate the `History` objects with the maximum of the related `Fund`, like:

```
History.objects.annotate(
    max_date=Max('fund__history__report_date')
).filter(
    report_date=F('max_date')
)
```

or a bit simpler:

```
History.objects.filter(
    report_date=Max('fund__history__report_date')
)
```

You can slightly improve performance with:

```
from django.db.models import Max, OuterRef, Subquery

History.objects.filter(
    report_date=Subquery(
        History.objects.filter(
            fund_id=OuterRef('fund_id')
        ).values('fund_id').annotate(
            last_date=Max('report_date')
        ).values('last_date')[:1]
    )
)
```

This will result in a query that looks like:

```
SELECT history.id, history.fund_id, history.purchase_nav_per_share, history.report_date
FROM history
WHERE history.report_date = (
    SELECT MAX(U0.report_date) AS last_date
    FROM history U0
    WHERE U0.fund_id = history.fund_id
    GROUP BY U0.fund_id
    LIMIT 1
)
```

The above is quite similar to the query in the question.

We here obtain the `History` objects, which is usually better than grasping the values itself since that is a sort of "*primitive obsession*" antipattern.

Comment: actually I want the value of **purchase_nav_per_share** related to the maximum report date for every fund_id.

Comment: @Erfan: but you get that: the `History` objects from this queryset of course have a `.purchase_nav_per_share` attribute.

Comment: the translation of your suggestion is a complex SQL query and I couldn't get the output according to its high execution time

Comment: @Erfan: it has two JOINs: one is on the `fund` model, which is always a single one, then another history, which will again result in some extra values. But in general both the queries in the question and answer should run in *O(n^2)* with *n* the number of `History`s.

Comment: I'm not sure but Django may translating it in an improper way which is the following sql code. I am using [django debug toolbars](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to retrieve sql query

Comment: `SELECT "FUNDS_HISTORY"."ID",  "FUNDS_HISTORY"."FUND_ID",  "FUNDS_HISTORY"."PURCHASE_NAV_PER_SHARE",  "FUNDS_HISTORY"."REPORT_DATE", MAX(T3."REPORT_DATE") AS "MAX_DATE" FROM "FUNDS_HISTORY" LEFT OUTER JOIN "FUNDS_FUND" ON ("FUNDS_HISTORY"."FUND_ID" = "FUNDS_FUND"."ID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "FUNDS_HISTORY" T3 ON ("FUNDS_FUND"."ID" = T3."FUND_ID") GROUP BY "FUNDS_HISTORY"."ID",  "FUNDS_HISTORY"."FUND_ID",  "FUNDS_HISTORY"."PURCHASE_NAV_PER_SHARE",  "FUNDS_HISTORY"."REPORT_DATE"  HAVING "FUNDS_HISTORY"."REPORT_DATE" = (MAX(T3."REPORT_DATE")) ORDER BY "FUNDS_HISTORY"."ID" ASC`

Comment: Well `T3` is a `fund_history` table, it is filtered (by the join) such that it has the same `fund_id` as the `fund_id` of the `fund_history` object.

Comment: I tried the latest query and it works however it is so slow whenever I want to iterate over it is object to extract data and generate my response

Answer (score 0):

You can translate above sql query as django ORM.

```
History.objects.annotate(report_date_max=Max('report_date')).filter(report_date=F('report_date_max')).values_list('fund_id', 'report_date', 'purchase_nav_per_share')
```

Model field names might be incorrect as you have not shared related field names.

Comment: thanks for response. your query seems to be same as following sql but I wan't the query returning one record per fund id while your suggestion does not provide my desirable output. `SELECT "funds_history"."fund_id",
       "funds_history"."report_date",
       "funds_history"."purchase_nav_per_share"
FROM "funds_history"
GROUP BY "funds_history"."id"
ORDER BY "funds_history"."id" ASC`

Comment: try this `History.objects.values_list('fund_id').annotate(report_date_max=Max('report_date')).filter(report_date=F('report_date_max')).values_list('fund_id', 'report_date', 'purchase_nav_per_share')`